# Leaflet - tooltips for overlapping polylines

Tags: leaflet, tooltip, polyline, overlapping

**Background:**
I am working on a web based mapping application for hiking. So the map based on leaflet offers routes on hiking trails that are labeled. As any hiking trail can be part of multiple routes, routes - respectively the corresponding polylines representing the routes - can overlap.

**Problem:**
Each route has its tooltip (triggered by mouseover, {sticky:true}) showing its label which works as expected for non-overlapping polylines but as soon as two or more routes overlap only the polyline "on top" gets its tooltip opened. This behaviour is not bad per se but as all routes are equally important I would like to show all labels of the routes at the pointer's location (or something like a maximum of 5 labels + x more). I weren't able to find any issue related to this topic.

**What I tried:**
- Create a feature group for all routes, bind the tooltip to the group, hoping that the tooltip function provides an array of all polylines crossing the pointer's position. As it turned out, I only get information of the polyline on top
- I tried the same with a mousemove event on the map, no success
- Comparing pointer's layerPoint coordinates with all routes' _rings & _parts layPoint arrays to find matching layerPoints, but the success rate is only about 5% as these layerPoints only cover actual points of the polyline but not the connection between two points. Additionally, there is a margin around each polyline that triggers the tolltip before the pointer even touches the polyline (too improve touch action, I guess)
- A solution to the margin problem is to add positive and negative margins to each polyline point before comparing it to the pointer coordinates which improves the outcome but doesn't solve the main problem.

**Sidenote:**
- All routes are drawn into a single canvas

Long story short, I need external help to accomplish the goal. Maybe some of you have an idea or can provide a solution. Any input is appreciated.

** ***UPDATE:*** **
A working but pretty inefficient solution is as follows

**Approach:**
Calculate the shortest distance from the pointer to all routes in viewport. If distance from  the pointer to a route is under a certain threshold, add them to the array of route labels that should be displayed.

**Steps:**
1.) bind a blank tooltip to the a feature group containing all routes
2.) bind mousemove event to the feature group with the follwing function

```
var routesFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup(routesGroup)
    .bindTooltip('', {sticky: true})
    .on('mousemove', function(e){
        var routeLabels   = [e.layer.options.label]; // add triggering route's label by default
        var mouseCoordAbs = el.$map.project(e.latlng);

        $.each(vars.objectsInViewport.routes, function(i, v){
            if (e.layer.options.id != el.$routes[i].options.id && el.$routes[i]._pxBounds.contains(e.layerPoint)){
                var nearestLatlngOnPolyline = getNearestPolylinePoint(e.latlng, el.$routes[i]);
                var polyPointCoordAbs = el.$map.project(nearestLatlngOnPolyline);

                var distToMouseX = polyPointCoordAbs.x - mouseCoordAbs.x;
                var distToMouseY = polyPointCoordAbs.y - mouseCoordAbs.y;
                var distToMouse  = Math.sqrt(distToMouseX*distToMouseX + distToMouseY*distToMouseY);

                if (distToMouse < 15) {
                    routeLabels.push(el.$routes[i].options.label);
                }
             }
        })

        var routesFeatureGroup.setTooltipContent(routeLabels.join('<br>'));
    })
```

**Explanation:**
I already gather all objects (routes and markers) in the current viewport for another part of the app. All routes currently visible are stored in vars.objectsInViewport.routes (respectively their ids), so I dont have to go through all routes. The layer that triggered the mousemove event is added by default. I then check for each of the routes currently visible if:
- their id is different to the layer that trigger the mousemove event (as this label is added by default)
- if their bounds (in cartesian coordinates: "_pxBounds") contain the cartesian layerPoint of the mousemove event (for a rough approch to exclude routes that don't intersect)

If these conditions are met for a route, calculate the closest latlng point from the pointer to the route. I do this with a custom function, which is a bit to long to post it in this context. (I will if someone asks for it)

The mouse position and the latlng point on the polyline / route are then converted to absolute coordinates using the map-project method 
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-project

At last, the distance between these to points is calculated using pythagoras. It is pixel based, so that the zoom level isn't a factor. If the distance is below a certain threshold (15px) they are close enough to the pointer to be considered as being hovered (with the default margins around a polyline), so the label of the route is added to the label array.

Finally the tooltip for the feature group is filled with all labels.

Results are pretty promising even though the operation is pretty expensive. I added a timeout of 50ms to reduce the function call a bit:

```
var tooltipTimeout;
var routesFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup(routesGroup)
    .bindTooltip('', {sticky: true})
    .on('mousemove', function(e){
        clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);

        tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            // collect labels
            // ...
        },50);
    .on('mouseout', function(){
        clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea of how to do this, but I am not 100% sure that it will do the job. There is a [plugin for Leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) (Mapbox) that can tell you if a point is within a Polygon and it returns all the Polygons that contain that point.

If this plugin doesn't work for polylines you can create a polygon from a polyline by just going back from the last point to the first and closing the line (I am not sure if this suits you solution). For example if you have a polyline of connected points of [0, 1, 2, .... n-1, n] you then go back with connecting [n with n-1, n-1 with n-2, ... 1 with 0]. This way you will have the same shape of the polyline but it will be a polygon. This isn't the most optimized solution, it is a quick fix that uses a known and available plugin.

Once you get all the tooltips, you can open all of them at once for each polygon/polyline. Or maybe open some helper tooltip where the user can select which one he wants to open.

I hope this helps! If you figure out a better solution (or find a plugin that does the job) please post it here.

Comment: I saw the leaflet pip-plugin (point in polygon) but I expect the follwing problem with this approach:  
by connecting the last point with the first, the polygon covers an area that is a lot larger than the polyline with a "weight". Imagine a long round route (start = end), all points within the route would match positive in this scenario, not matter if the cursor is 2px or 400px away from that route.  
  
I added a possible but expensive solution to the original post which is working.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that you connect the last point with the first but for example if you have [0,1,2,3,4...n-1,n] points that represent your polyline you then go backwards and connect [n with n-1, n-1 with n-2, ... 1 with 0]. I know this is not an optimized solution but it is a quick fix that uses a known plugin.

Comment: ah, thanks for the clarification. This would probably work except for the "problem" that this approch doesn't take the margin / weight of polylines into consideration that triggers the tooltip to make that feature more usable.